# How to extract decimal number from currency using Regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of currency in string. I want to extract only the decimal numbers from that list.
how can I do so ?

I tried the below code but it gives me an extra point in front of each value.

```
list1 = ['Rs.35,916.00', 'Rs.35,916.00', 'Rs.45,000.00']
for i in list1: 
    value = (sub(r'[^\d.]', '', i))
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
.35916.00
.35916.00
.45000.00
```

expected output:

```
 35916.00
 35916.00
 45000.00
```

Comment: `value = re.sub(r'Rs\.|[^\d.]', '', i, fags=re.I)`

Comment: Better, without  regex, `value = i.replace('Rs.', '').replace(',', '')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for this simple and effective idea.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
list1 = ['Rs.35,916.00', 'Rs.35,916.00', 'Rs.45,000.00']
for i in list1: 
    value = (sub(r'Rs\.|[^\d.]', '', i))
    print(value)
```